# syntax error, unexpected ')' in eval code

Tags: php

Understand that there is plenty of unexpected questions about eval'd code, but none that would help me figure this particular piece:

`@eval('$return=(bool)('. $test.');');`

Any ideas?

The full code that presents the error is

```
$notfound = TRUE;
                            if (isset($child['when'])) {
                                foreach ($child['when'] as $grandchild)  {
                                    $test = $this->build_mask($datatree, $grandchild['test'], $direction, $cindex, $clast, $ckey, TRUE, $carray);
                                    $return = NULL;
                                    @eval('$return=(bool)('. $test .');');
                                    if ($return === TRUE) {
                                        $notfound = FALSE;
                                        $built[] = $this->build_mask($datatree, $grandchild['true'], $direction, $cindex, $clast, $ckey, $incode, $carray);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

Comment: did you know when the `unexpected ')'` error occur?

Comment: Im using bugsnag which finds the error.

Comment: Never use @ to hide errors. Instead ON error_reporting  in development mode.

Comment: I don't know why you have used eval() but you can write eval('$return=(bool)($test);');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below code:-

```
$test = 'XXX';
eval('$return=(bool)$test;');
if($return){  // true
    // do your stuff
}
```

You can simply write it as:-

```
$test = 'XXX';
$return=(bool)$test;
if($return){  // true
    // do your stuff
}
```

OR use [!empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) to avoid unnecessary type casting.

```
$test = 'XXX';
if(!empty($test)){ // true
    // do your stuff
}
```

**Suggestion**:- Never use @ to hide your errors. You should ON your [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) in development mode.

Comment: Yup, that's done it. Ive inherited the template code - its the first time I've really had bugsnag running on the CMS its used on. Thank you